# How can I change the indices of an R vector?

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I would like to plot as lines the results of different random vectors (look at them like random walks), such that each one of them follows in a sequence after the previous one.

To do so, I'd like the indexing of the second vector to start where the first one ended.

For instance in the case of

```
a <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
b <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
head(a)
[1] -0.03900184 -0.37913568 -0.42521156
head(b)
[1]  1.3861861 -0.2418804  1.1159065
```

Both vectors are naturally indexed from `[1]` to `[10]`. So if I plot them, they overlap (left plot), while what I would like is for `b` to follow `a` in the `x`-axis (right plot):

```
plot(a, type = "l", xlim=c(0,20), ylim=c(-10,10), xlab="", ylab="", col=2)
lines(b, col=3)
```

[image]

Appending `b` to `a` seems to be an avenue, but when I subset the resulting vector, I end up again with a vector that starts at zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `x` argument in the `lines` function.

```
set.seed(146)

a <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
b <- cumsum(rnorm(10))

plot(a, type = "l", xlim=c(0,20), ylim=c(-10,10), xlab="", ylab="", col=2)
lines(x = 10:19, y = b, col=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can create a new `b` with `NA`s till `length(a) -1` and then add last value of `a` and then append `b` and then use this `new_b` in `lines` argument.

```
set.seed(1)

a <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
b <- cumsum(rnorm(10))

new_b <- c(rep(NA, length(a)-1),a[length(a)], b)

plot(a, type = "l", xlim=c(0,20), ylim=c(-10,10), xlab="", ylab="", col=2)
lines(new_b, col=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this using `ggplot2`?

```
library(tidyverse);
set.seed(2017);
a <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
b <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
stack(data.frame(a, b)) %>%
    rowid_to_column("x") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, values)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = ind))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the data point index is important for you I am assuming you are working with a time series type data. You should consider time series indexing of your object creation and subsetting for desired manipulation. Here is an example

```
foo <- ts(1:10, frequency = 1, start = 1)

# Subset using time series indexing
foo1 <- ts(foo[1:5], start = index(foo)[1], frequency = frequency(foo))
foo6 <- ts(foo[6:10], start  = index(foo)[6], frequency = frequency(foo))

# Combine using appropriate index    
fooNew <- ts(c(foo1, foo6), start = start(foo1), frequency = frequency(foo1))
```